# I was offered a project management job recently but I realized the products they are building do not have market value, how can I handle this?

Tags: project-management

The product they are building is for the healthcare system with the major target on healthcare workers. They are focused on communication, collaboration and scheduling.

Comment: This question was migrated because it's  really more about how to evaluate a potential job than it is about project management, or the Product Owner role within a given project management framework.

Comment: There is a niche market in healthcare for smaller EHR and patient management platforms. Competitors like Oracle and Epic control about 60% of the market together but are focused on multi-practice organizations and cost millions plus. Some platforms have traction as they layer into existing platforms. Sounds like you should eval for market position and target audience as well.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few things to consider:

- Will the lack of market value reduce the viability of the company and hence reduce your job security?
- Does the lack of market value reduce your passion and enthusiasm for the work?
- Does the lack of market value imply some fundamental issues with how the company is run (in that they are trying to build something that likely won't sell)?

I would suggest raising these concerns with somebody at the company. If they can put your mind at rest, then you should feel confident to proceed with the role.

Answer (score 3):

Your realization is out of scope...unless part of your scope is to refresh its business case. I suspect it's not, so what you realize or don't realize is irrelevant. And if you spent time doing the market research you would need to do to determine a product's viability in the marketplace, I would not bill your customer for that time and effort. Again, because that work is out of scope.

Just build the product and deliver it.

Comment: I don't get why this was downvoted. David is on spot. As a *project* manager, your work is to deliver the project. If the position was for product manager, then the answer would be different. Maybe the downvote comes from a semantic confusion?

Comment: There is a movement to expand the importance of project management higher than managing the project. It's been going on for years. I reject the entire movement but I suspect the down vote came from someone who wants the pm to be on a higher status.

Comment: That could be it indeed, David. I don't get this eager we see in IT to catalyse the semantic diffusion of our terminology.